# Tinkerpop Blueprints Vertex Query

Tags: neo4j, orientdb, titan, tinkerpop

I've been researching the Tinkerpop stack for quite a while. I think I have a good idea of what it can do and what databases it works well with. I've got a couple of different databases I'm thinking about right now, but haven't decided on a definite. So I've decided to write my code purely to the interfaces, and not take into account *any* implementation right now. Out of the databases I'm looking at, they implement `TransactionalGraph` and `KeyIndexableGraph`. I think that's good enough for what I need, but I have just one question.

I have different 'classes' of vertices. Using Blueprints, I believe that's best representable by having a field in each vertex containing the class name. Doing that, I can do something like `graph.getVertices("classname", "User")` and it would give me all of the user vertices. And since the `getVertices` function specifies that an implementation should make use of indexes, I'm guaranteed to get a fast lookup (if I index that field).

But let's say that I wanted to retrieve a vertex based on two properties. The vertex must have `className=Users` and `username=admin`. What's the best way to go about finding that single vertex? And is it possible to index over both of those properties, even though not all vertices will have a `username` field?

FYI - The databases I'm currently thinking of are OrientDB, Neo4j and Titan, but I haven't decided for sure yet. I'm also currently planning to use Gremlin if that helps at all.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

1. `graph.getVertices()` will iterate through all vertexes and look for ones with that property if you do not have the auto-index turned on in your graph implementation. If you already have data and cannot just turn on the auto-indexer, you should use is `index = indexableGraph.getIndex()` and then `index.get('classname', 'User')`
2. It's possible to perform a `query` over multiple objects, but without specifics, it's hard to say. For `Neo4j` they use Lucene, which means that `query()` will take a lucene query, such as `className:Users AND username:admin`, but I cannot speak for the others.

Yeah of those DB is good for playing with, I personally found `neo4j` to be the easiest, and as long as you understand their licensing structure, you shouldn't have any problems using them.

Comment: Well, as you said, the queries are somewhat implementation specific (unfortunately). I want the ability to switch DBs at any time, so I just wrote my own query wrapper. Thanks for your help.

Comment: Yeah, it's unfortunate, but that's the way most of these systems are build, some may not have the capability to perform certain types of query's, so they left it to be implementation specific.

Comment: It's not quite correct to say that `graph.getVertices()` does a linear scan.  If the graph implements KeyIndexableGraph (and all three graphs mentioned do) and the key specified is one created as a key index, then  the index is used and the linear scan avoided.  https://github.com/tinkerpop/blueprints/wiki/Graph-Indices#keyindexablegraph-and-fast-lookup-of-elements-by-keyvalue-pairs

Comment: Sorry, I forgot about the auto-indexer. I assumed that he was talking about if he didn't have that enabled. I have updated my answer, thanks.

Answer (score 4):

Using a "class" or a "type" for vertices is a good way to segment them.  Doing:

```
graph.createKeyIndex("classname",Vertex.class);
graph.getVertices("classname", "User");
```

is a pretty common pattern and should generally yield a fast lookup, though iterating an index of tens of millions of users might not be so great (if you intend to grow a particular `classname` to very big size).  I think that leads to the second part of your question, in regards to doing a two property lookup.

Taking your example on the surface, the two element lookup would be something like (using Gremlin):

```
g.V('classname',"User").has('username','admin')
```

So, you narrow the vertices to just "User" vertices with a key index and then filter those for "admin".  But, I'd model this differently.  It would be even less expensive to simply do:

```
graph.createKeyIndex("username",Vertex.class);
graph.getVertices("username", "admin");
```

or in Gremlin:

```
g.V('username','admin')
```

If you know the username you want, there's no better/faster way to model this.  You really only need the `classname` if you want to iterate over all "User" vertices.  If you just want to find one (or a set of vertices with that `username`) then key indexing on that property is the better way.

Even if I don't create a key index on it, I still include a `type` or `classname` property on all vertices.  I find it helpful in global operations where I may or may not care about speed, but just need an answer.

Comment: The problem with this is that I can't guarantee that the User class will be the only vertex class with the username field. Our data model is flexible and indirectly editable by the user. There's no guarantee that vertices of different classes won't share property names.

Comment: Not a problem at all.  The index doesn't need to uniquely identify the specific user (though it's nice when it can).  Use the index to get you close and then filter on class.  Consider the difference of: `g.V('classname','user').has('username','admin')` and `g.V('username','admin').has('classname','user')`.  The first has to get all the users (maybe thousands or more) and then cycle them to find "admin".  The second is much better as even if 'username' exists more than once in the graph, it's probably not going to return thousands, so you only scan a handful to find the 'user' class.

Comment: Or, ensure uniqueness in your schema.  If you don't mind verbosity in your property names there's no reason you can't prefix it with the type name.  So maybe you feel you need to store username in the "user" class and a "blog" class (to denote who wrote a post).  just call the "user" class vertex property "username" and call the "blog" class property "blogUsername".   That way you ensure your index always returns one thing from one class.